# Ax2012 bill of material (BOM) for an Item

Tags: axapta

I am in a requirement for validating if the item has a BOM associated with it, can anyone please help me in finding if The item has a BOM or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a bill of material exists for an item, you can query the `BOMVersion` table if it has an entry for the item.

To check if an item is used in a bill of material, you can query the `BOM` table if it has an entry for the item.